# Force uninstall Windows Store application

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall

I have a Windows 10 installation where some applications were installed on an SD card. Then the SD card was removed and replaced; it is not available anymore. Since then the applications can't be used, but worse than that, they constantly try to update and fail. An attempt to uninstall them fails too. I tried to do it via PowerShell commands; they fail with "drive unmounted" error, which is quite logical. It there a possibility to forcibly uninstall store applications, removing the installation information even if the original drive is not available?